# Is it possible to use parameter value in web.config attributes

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config

What I am trying to achieve is to set web.config rules with parameters for it's attributes, mainly to avoid duplications. for example (from rewrite module):

```
 <rule name="Test11" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="test11" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
      <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone|android|iphone|ipad" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="test1/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
  </rule>

  <rule name="Test22" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="test22" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
      <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone|android|iphone|ipad" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="test2/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
  </rule>
```

Convert to:

```
<rule name="Test11" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="test11" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
      <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="`[MyParameter]`" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="test1/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
  </rule>

  <rule name="Test22" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="test22" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
      <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="**[MyParameter]**" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="test2/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
  </rule>
```

Note that the rewrite rules are not the main issue but the ability of using parameters is.

Comment: Could [maps](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module) help?

Comment: I can hardly see how